# In .net core in docker, how can I see the host's IP adress?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

The scenario is like this:

I have a .net Core docker image that runs on a laptop, where other laptops should be able to access it, ususally on an ad hoc local network with no internet access.

On the server laptop it is just:  http://localhost:23456

But when other laptops connects it is something like: http://192.168.1.12:23456

So I would like that when at app is started up on the server laptop on: http://localhost:23456
the app could resolve the hosts IP address and write:

"For client laptops connecting to this server use this address: [http://192.168.1.12:23456"](http://192.168.1.12:23456%22)

Comment: This is what you're asking? docker container ip within a .net core application

Comment: This is something Docker intentionally hides from you.  The linked question has several ways to get _an_ address, but for this particular application the better answers come down to "pass it in as an environment variable".